# I have an unknown problem with datepicker

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, jquery-ui-datepicker, sweetalert2

```
var form = document.createElement("div");
form.innerHTML = "<input type='text'  id='Test'>";

swal({
  content: form,
  closeOnEsc: false,
  closeOnClickOutside: false,
});

$('#Test').datepicker();
```

The `swal` is displayed without any problem and also input but when I click on input nothing happens.

When I do the same thing in `body` and out of swal(without sweet alert) its ok and datepicker is active and I can choose a time but the problem is happened when I using swal

Comment: It may be the case that the `datepicker` library needs the element to be part of the DOM before you instantiate it (so that it knows where to position the dropdowns etc). Try appending the element to the DOM first, *then* calling `datepicker()` on the `input`

Comment: what is `swal()`

Comment: @MarkSchultheiss a common library

Comment: @epascarello Perhaps, but not tagged as such...

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please visit [help], take [tour] to see what and [ask]. Do some research, search for related topics on SO; if you get stuck, post a [mcve] of your attempt, noting input and expected output, preferably in a [Stacksnippet](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. You may have assigned the `datepicker` before the input was appended to the DOM. This would cause it to fail. Do you see any errors in console?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using [didOpen](https://sweetalert2.github.io/#didOpen) with the current approach

```js
Swal.fire({
  title: 'My Form',
  html: `<input type='text'  id='Test'>`,
  didOpen: function () {
    $('#Test').datepicker();  
  }
});
```

```html
<link href="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.13.2/themes/black-tie/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<script
  src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.1.min.js"
  integrity="sha256-o88AwQnZB+VDvE9tvIXrMQaPlFFSUTR+nldQm1LuPXQ="
  crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/sweetalert2@11"></script>


<script
  src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.13.2/jquery-ui.min.js"
  integrity="sha256-lSjKY0/srUM9BE3dPm+c4fBo1dky2v27Gdjm2uoZaL0="
  crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

Answer (score 1):

You could try the didOpen function:

> Popup lifecycle hook. Asynchronously runs after the popup has been
> shown on screen. Provides popup DOM element as the argument

```
var form = document.createElement("div");
form.innerHTML = "<input type='text'  id='Test'>";

swal({
  content: form,
  closeOnEsc: false,
  closeOnClickOutside: false,
  didOpen:function(el){
    $('#Test').datepicker();
  }
});
```